# Auth::user return null in laravel custom login

Tags: laravel

Users, roles, permissions have in my project.I have use custom login. I call `Auth::user()` return null.

How can I fix that?

```
    public function check(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $userInfo = User::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

    if(!$userInfo){
        return back()->with('message', 'We do not recognize your email address');
    } 
    
    if($userInfo){
        if(Hash::check($request->password, $userInfo->password)){
            $request->session()->put('isUser', $userInfo->id);
            $user = User::where('id', '=', session('isUser'))->first();
            dd(Auth::user());
            // dd($userInfo->roles);
            // return redirect('home');
        } else {
            return back()->with('message', 'Incorrect password');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Auth::login($userId)` after you've used you're own custom login.

Comment: $user = User::where('id', '=', session('isUser'))->first();
 dd(Auth::login($user));
Still return null

Comment: how can i solve that? please bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the user instance to `Auth::login()` like this: `Auth::user($user);`;